# NaN loss and also NaN output during training using custom training loop

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, deep-learning

I am trying to train a network, which takes as input, output from the last convolutional layers of 3 pre-trained models (VGG NET).

Now, the problem I am dealing with is a multi-label classification problem.

```
def grads_ds(model_ds, ds_inputs,y_true,cw):
    with tf.GradientTape() as ds_tape:
        y_pred = model_ds(ds_inputs)
        #print(y_pred)
        logits_1 = -1*y_true*K.log(y_pred)*cw[:,0]
        logits_0 = -1*(1-y_true)*K.log(1-y_pred)*cw[:,1]
        loss = logits_1 + logits_0
        loss_value_ds = K.sum(loss)

    #print(loss_value_ds)

    ds_grads = ds_tape.gradient(loss_value_ds,model_ds.trainable_variables,unconnected_gradients=tf.UnconnectedGradients.NONE)
    return loss_value_ds, ds_grads
```

This is the code for calculating gradients, as I am using a custom training loop.

I have formulated this problem as 3 binary classification problem (3 classes), hence I have tried to calculated binary cross-entropy for each of them. Also I have applied `sigmoid` activation to the output.

Furthermore, the classes are imbalanced, hence, I have also used class weights.

Example of class weights:

```
[[0.61883899 2.60368664]
 [2.71634615 0.61279826]
 [1.4231738  0.77080491]]
```

When the training started, the gradient values changes between magnitude of orders of 1e-1 to 1e-8 and vice-versa. After about 20 iterations, the gradient values change to `nan` suddenly.

All I can think of is some issue in the manual calculation of the loss function, that amy be causing the problem, which I did becasue ofabsence of any weighted binary cross-entropy function in tensorflow.

Another thing is that the pre-trained layers are frozen and are not fine-tuned. Only the dense layers connected to the output of the pre-trained model are being trained.

The output is of shape 41472, to which a FC layer of shape 2048 is connected, followed by another dense layer of shape 3 (for output).

The optimizer I am using is `Adam(lr=1e-5)`

Each batch containes 16 images. Total number of trainable parameters is about 85 million.

What is the reason for getting `nan` loss and also `nan` output value?

Comment: using log can be very infamous log(-x)... I know that y_pred are always [0,1] but I try to make some check ensuring that they always are positive, for example forcing with K.clip. what about also y_pred exactly equal 0 ==> log(0)?

Comment: @MarcoCerliani y_pred is always positive since I am using sigmoid activation. But yes, it can be very close to zero.

Comment: @MarcoCerliani I used K.clip, but the values I am getting are not looking like K.clip is having any effect on theoriginal values